# Discarding count in <expr> mappings

Tags: vim, mapping, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, I have the following expression mapping:


```
    function! DelNthSpace()
        let col=match(getline('.'), '[[:blank:] ]', col('.'), v:count1)
        return virtcol([line('.'), col+1])."|s \e"
    endfunction
    nnoremap  s DelNthSpace()
```


You see, `v:count1` is already handled here. But if I try to replace second space with such function that is located, for example, at virtual column `35` (it will be if you place cursor on the return statement), then this tries to go to column `235` and replace it because this will be transformed from `2s` to `2{DelNthSpace()}` -> `235|s ^[`. Now I am prepending bare useless `|` at the start of return statement which consumes unneeded count, but I do not like this solution as it uses two movements instead of one.

**UPDATE**: I should have provided more context:

```
function! ToNthSpace()
    let col=match(getline('.'), '[[:blank:] ]', col('.'), v:count1)
    return virtcol([line('.'), col+1])."|"
endfunction
noremap <expr> s ToNthSpace()
```

There are a bunch of functions that are using these, one imitates replace command, but transliterates its argument (so, while calling `r$ii` will replace character with `$` and insert `i`, `\tr$ii` will replace character with `∬`, same relation between `t` and `\tt` and some others), others are motions. As these functions define motions, I can't use `:<C-u>`, it will leave visual mode (or I will have to add a hack which will tell from which mode function was called). I do not know this hack and I can't define different mappings for normal and visual modes.

Comment: I am upvoting because the title asks what i need myself, but it is hard to get through the text, not clear to me if giving all the details of a very special application is necessary.

Comment: I have a related question: if you have entered a count in Vim in Visual mode, for example, but then decided that the count was wrong or unnecessary, how can you cancel the count without leaving Visual mode?

Comment: @Alexey It seems you have answered your own question: `@_` works for this. No way to do this in operator-pending mode I know about (and I actually did not know about `@_`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make vim ignore the count for the `<expr>` mapping, however you can easily change your mapping to make your function work:

```
nnoremap s :<C-U>exe 'normal!' DelNthSpace()<CR>
```

See `:help v:count` for info about using `CTRL+U` to erase the count.

Comment: No, I can't. 1. `DelNthSpace` is actually a function that uses `getchar()` and it may accidently catch parts of next command, `normal! ` will discard them. 2. I use self-written plugin for defining mappings, it does not allow anything except expression mappings and I won't rewrite that. But you have somehow pointed me to a solution (not working as motion in visual mode, so it was thrown away) (return `":\<C-u>normal! ".vcol."|\n".":\<C-u>call feedkeys(".substitute(string(nextcmd), '\n', '''."\<CR>".''', 'g').")\n"`. Will wait, maybe someone will find a better solution.

Comment: I've found a couple of ways to make Vim ignore [count] in Normal mode: press `<Esc>` or `@_`.  The second one (`@_`) also works in Visual mode.  I wonder if there is a way to ignore [count] in Operator-pending mode.

Comment: @Alexey I found your way particularly useful. This should be accepted as an answer. I do also need a way to cancel the count in `omap`. But the `<Esc>` will cancel the whole operation.

Comment: @Alexey, I found a wordaround that is to return `printf(':normal %s', rv)` instead. This works when the expression you want return (i.e. `rv`) specifies a cursor position

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what is mentioned by @Alexey and also my test on `operator-pending` mode, you can do the following

```
nnoremap <expr> s "@_" . ToNthSpace()
vnoremap <expr> s "@_" . ToNthSpace()
onoremap <expr> s printf(":normal %s\<cr>", ToNthSpace())
```

Then the `2` already typed in your example will have no effect